# How to solve JSON decodable bad exception using Swift 4.2?

Tags: json, swift

My scenario, I am trying to get `data` from `JSON` and loading into `tableView`. While `compile` time I am getting `badexception` from JSON `decodable` process. below JSON response I am using, I cant able to get exact `issues`. Please provide some suggestion

My JSON Response

```
{
  "status": true,
  "status_code": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "cat_id": "1",
      "cat_name": "Food",
      "cat_parentid": "2",
      "name": "guru",
      "year": "3000",
      "fullname": {
        "firstname": "jio",
        "lastname": "jack"
      },
      "address": {
        "city": "sanfrancisco",
        "state": "california"
      },
      "ship": {
        "captian": "mojo",
        "time": "12.30.01"
      }
    }
   ]
}
```

My Decodable

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let catID, catName, catParentid, name, year: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case catID = "cat_id"
        case catName = "cat_name"
        case catParentid = "cat_parentid"
        case name, year
    }
}
```

My JSON Code

```
func parseJSON() {

        let url = URL(string: "https://...")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("returning error")
            return
        }

        guard let content = data else {
            print("not returning data")
            return
        }

        guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

            do {
                let content = json["data"] as! [[String:String]]
                let staData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:content,options:[])
                self.tableArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from:staData)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }

        print(self.tableArray)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

My issue

[image: issue screen]

Comment: Please read the JSON carefully. The value for key `data` is not an array of `[String:String]` dictionaries, for example the value for key `fullname` is not `String`. And why do you deserialize the JSON twice? That's unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what I did mistake. Could you please tell me where I repeated deserialize into my code? @vadian

Comment: If the JSON in the question is your JSON response you ***de**serialize* it to dictionary (before the `do` block), then you *serialize* the array for key `data` and ***de**serialize* it again to avoid the umbrella struct for the JSON Decoder. That's not a good practice.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code for correct one. I am very new for this @vadian

Comment: Please first **you** add the code what's happening before the `do` block and please as text, not as image.

Comment: I updated my question. Please check it @vadian

Comment: Basically use Gereon's structs. Delete the entire  expression `guard let json = (try? ...  return }`. Further delete the first two lines in the do `block` and in the next line replace `staData` with `content` and `[Root]` with `Root`.

Comment: I cant able to understand what your trying to say. Please post some answer it will be more helpful for me and others too @vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have generated `Codable` protocol from [HERE](https://app.quicktype.io/?share=2O9jStiO6T444YFJc8F3) and it will look like:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let statusCode: Int
    let data: [Datum]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case statusCode = "status_code"
        case data
    }
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let catID, catName, catParentid, name: String
    let year: String
    let fullname: Fullname
    let address: Address
    let ship: Ship

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case catID = "cat_id"
        case catName = "cat_name"
        case catParentid = "cat_parentid"
        case name, year, fullname, address, ship
    }
}

struct Address: Codable {
    let city, state: String
}

struct Fullname: Codable {
    let firstname, lastname: String
}

struct Ship: Codable {
    let captian, time: String
}
```

Now I have checked it on Playground with your `JSON` which is look like below:

```
let jsonData = """
{
  "status": true,
  "status_code": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "cat_id": "1",
      "cat_name": "Food",
      "cat_parentid": "2",
      "name": "guru",
      "year": "3000",
      "fullname": {
        "firstname": "jio",
        "lastname": "jack"
      },
      "address": {
        "city": "sanfrancisco",
        "state": "california"
      },
      "ship": {
        "captian": "mojo",
        "time": "12.30.01"
      }
    }
   ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

And you can parse it like:

```
let root = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
```

Now you can get data array from `root` object with

```
let content = root?.data //here your crash will resolve
```

`content` is a type of `[Datum]`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write your structs to match the structure of your JSON data exactly, like these:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let statusCode: Int
    let data: [Datum]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case statusCode = "status_code"
        case data
    }
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let catID, catName, catParentid, name: String
    let year: String
    let fullname: Fullname
    let address: Address
    let ship: Ship

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case catID = "cat_id"
        case catName = "cat_name"
        case catParentid = "cat_parentid"
        case name, year, fullname, address, ship
    }
}

struct Address: Codable {
    let city, state: String
}

struct Fullname: Codable {
    let firstname, lastname: String
}

struct Ship: Codable {
    let captian, time: String
}
```

With these, you can simply use `JSONDecoder` without any need for `JSONSerialization`

Comment: Great help @Gereon I will check and update you here. Thank you.

Comment: Same exception I am getting on same line @Gereon

Comment: @iosdev You need to use `Root.self` instead of `[Root].self` like: `try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, ....`

Answer (score 1):

First of all use the structs provided by Gereon.

Then replace your function with

```
func parseJSON() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://...")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in

        if let error = error { print("returning error", error); return }

        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:data!)
            self.tableArray = result.data
            print(self.tableArray)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            self.tableArray = []
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: awesome you are the master iOS. Thanks @vadian